# How does one contract send ether to another contract with more than 2300 gas?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, contract-invocation

I want one contract to collect a certain amount of finney before sending it to another contract, but I can't simply send in with `C2.send(thisMuch)`.

```
function() {
    Dividend m = Dividend(dividendAddr);
    if (this.balance >= 70 finney) {
        uint sendProfit = this.balance;
    }
    m.Enter.send(sendProfit);
}
```

This is what I have so far, but I'm completely lost when it comes to sending finney from one contract to the next. How can I do that?

I have made two contracts on how I think it should work.
Contract one sends it to contract two.

```
contract one {

    address public deployer;
    address public targetAddress;


    modifier execute {
        if (msg.sender == deployer) {
            _
        }
    }


    function one(address _targetAddress) {
        deployer = msg.sender;
        targetAddress = _targetAddress;
    }


    function forward() {
        two m = two(targetAddress);
        m.pay();
        targetAddress.send(this.balance);
    }


    function() {
        forward();
    }


    function sendBack() execute {
        deployer.send(this.balance);
    }


}
```

Contract two sends it back to me.

```
contract two {

    address public deployer;

    function two() {
        deployer = msg.sender;
    }

    function pay() {
        deployer.send(this.balance);
    }

    function() {
        pay();
    }

}
```

Is this how it should work?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In order to send Ether to another contract while specifying the amount of gas, use the `call` function.

`targetAddress.call.gas(200000).value(this.balance)();` will call the fallback function.

`targetAddress.call.gas(200000).value(this.balance)(bytes4(sha3("pay()")));` will call the `pay` function.

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately http://etherscan.io/address/0x845f74aac51148bdd4ef6aed29822940c025a3a2

Comment: You set the gas to 200,000 but you only gave the transaction 134968. That's what caused the error

Comment: It worked, but I didn't see at first - in mist - that you can change the amount of gas in the same window as where you put your password in.

Comment: Is there a return value handling for this mechanism? As it doesn't know about the type of the return value? For example `send()` returns bool if the transaction succeeded.

Comment: No, you can't get a return value from a low-level call. If you know the return type, you should use the `myContract.myMethod.value(1 ether).gas(30000)(arg1,arg2)`. Fallback functions don't return values anyway

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to specify the transmitted value and used gas for each external function (and constructor) call:

```
contract Fa { function fa(uint _a) {} }

contract Fb {
  function fb(address a) {
     Fa b= Fa(a);// or Fa b = New Fa.value(2).gas(200)(a);
    b.fa.value(3).gas(1500)(50);
  }
}
```

`f.gas(x).value(20)()` calls the modified function f and thereby sending 20 Wei (or 20 ether by value(20 ether)) and limiting the gas to x (so this function call will most likely go out of gas and return your 20 Wei).

NB : `send()` should actually use min gas. If we want the code to be executed, we should use `call()`

Answer (score 1):

Calling external functions is documented [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/control-structures.html#external-function-calls). To the best of my knowledge, there's no way to send to the default function with a user-specified amount of gas; you have to call a named function.

Answer (score 0):

Functions that send Ether shall be marked as payable: 
    function name(args) payable { 
      //do something 
    }

Comment: Do you mean _receive_ ether? https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html?highlight=payable#modifiers